# PHP : PDO Connection Set-up Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Inside my Database file:

```
class StructureFactory
{
    // Default values
    protected $provider = null;
    protected $connection = null;

    // When Class is called, we send the $provider to it
    public function __construct( callable $provider )
    {
        // replace the $provider in the Class to the sent in $provider
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }

    public function create( $name )
    {
        if ( $this->connection === null )
        {
            // Create a new connection with the send in name
            $this->connection = call_user_func( $this->provider );
        }
        return new $name( $this->connection );
    }

}


$provider = function()
{
    // New provider variables
    $instance = new PDO('mysql:dbname:DBNAME;host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'userHERE', 'passHERE');
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    return $instance;
};

// send the new provider
$factory = new StructureFactory( $provider );

// Create a new connection with $db
function open_database($factory){
    $db = $factory->create('db');
    global $db;
}
```

to call the database connection:

```
define('FILE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
    require_once FILE_ROOT.'inc/database.php';
    open_database($factory);

    foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name") as $row) { echo $row['columnName']; }
```

But I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'db' not found in /home/kyleport/public_html/inc/database.php on line 23

Can anyone please reference anything that will help me try to fix this? I am struggling so badly.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php - the fourth parameter is an array of options. The database name is part of your DSN

Comment: so where does the database name go? @andrewsi

Comment: Did you look at the link? It shows you how you need to do this

Comment: I did but that doesn't say where I target what Database name I am using :/ & now I receive this error removing it: > 
Fatal error: Class 'db' not found in /home/kyleport/public_html/inc/database.php on line 23

Comment: Yes, it does. It's right there in Example 1: `$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';`

Comment: You're also wrapping things in functions that you don't need to; your `$provider` doesn't need to be in a function, nor does `open_database()`

Comment: Your actual error was: `mysql:dbname:DBNAME;` should be: `mysql:dbname=DBNAME;`. Note the '=' not ':'. `PDO` is very particular about the `dsn` but doesn't validate it  correctly if the host is `localhost`. Guess how I found out? ;-/

Comment: I edited my answer according tou your edit of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like

```
new PDO('mysql:host=myHost;dbname=myDB;charset=myCharset',$user, $pass, $options_array)
```

in your case options_array could already set those attributes:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=myHost;dbname=myDB;charset=myCharset',$user, $pass,  array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false));
```

Edit: ok you edited the Question...
You have the line

```
return new $name( $this->connection );
```

in your code and you call it with `$name = 'db';`

so it will execute as `return new db( $this->connection );`
But at this point you obviously have no class with the name 'db'.